# Exiting system upon selecting the x button in the top right corner of a showMessageDialog box in Java?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I want to know how to cause a program to exit upon selecting the X button of a showMessageDialog dialog box. 
Currently whenever I do this, it simply continues running the code or, in the case of confirm or option dialog boxes, selects the 'Yes' option. Is it possible to include this kind of command in the code for the dialog box? For example:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your message here");
```

How would I edit the output so that the X button closes the program?

Will I have to change the showMessageDialog to another type of dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is this what you want but i put a *confirm box* in a program:

```
    (...)
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
    (...)
    createButton(buttons, "&Exit", "Exit", new MySelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent evt) {
            MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(getShell(), SWT.YES | SWT.NO | SWT.ICON_QUESTION);
            messageBox.setMessage("Are you sure?");
            messageBox.setText("Exit");
            if (messageBox.open() == SWT.YES) {
                getParent().dispose();
            }
        }
    });
```

And looking at [online javadoc (java 6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) or [(java 1.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), you have another option:

> **Direct Use:**
>   To create and use an JOptionPane directly, the standard pattern is roughly as follows:

```
 JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
 pane.set.Xxxx(...); // Configure
 JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
 dialog.show();
 Object selectedValue = pane.getValue();
 if(selectedValue == null)
   return CLOSED_OPTION;
 //If there is not an array of option buttons:
 if(options == null) {
   if(selectedValue instanceof Integer)
      return ((Integer)selectedValue).intValue();
   return CLOSED_OPTION;
 }
 //If there is an array of option buttons:
 for(int counter = 0, maxCounter = options.length;
    counter < maxCounter; counter++) {
    if(options[counter].equals(selectedValue))
    return counter;
 }
 return CLOSED_OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

`showMessageDialog()` doesn't have a return value.  Here is an example with `showOptionsDialog()`.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Test");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                        "Your message here", "", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new String[] {"OK"}, "OK");
                if (result == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            }
        });

        panel.add(button);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```